# Addition of polynomials with different grade

Tags: c++

I'm currently writing a code that sums together the coefficient of two polynomials.
This all works fine as long as the grade of the first polynomial is smaller or equal to the second. "if (d1 <= d2)"

However, when "d1 > d2", the code seems to have some kind of issue I don't understand.
I'm sitting on this for a while now but don't seem to find the problem. Does anybody have any hints?
Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

double * poli_sum (double * p1, int d1, double * p2, int d2, int & dr);


double * read_poly(int &n){
  cout << "Grade of function: ";
  cin >> n;
  double * c=new double[n+1];
  for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
    cout << "Coefficient of degree " << i << ": ";
    cin >> c[i];
  }
  return c;
}

double * read_second_poly(int &m){
  cout << "Grade of second function: ";
  cin >> m;
  double * g=new double[m+1];
  for(int i=0;i<=m;i++){
    cout << "Coefficient of degree " << i << ": ";
    cin >> g[i];
  }
  return g;
}


double * poli_sum (double * p1, int d1, double * p2, int d2, int & dr){

    dr = 0;

    if (d1 <= d2){
            cout << "You're in first, d1 = " << d1 << endl;
            cout << "d2 = " << d2 << endl <<endl;

        for (int i = 0; i <= d2; i++){
          if (i >d1) p1[i] = 0; // setting array[i] to zero when it gets outside the defined grade
          cout << (p1[i]+p2[i])<< endl;

          cout << "pi1( "<< i << "): "<< p1[i] << endl;
          cout << "pi2( "<< i << "): "<< p2[i] << endl << endl;
          dr++;
        }
    }

    else if (d1 > d2){
          cout << "You're in second, d1 = " << d1 << endl;
          cout << "d2 = " << d2 << endl <<endl;

        for (int i = 0; i <= d1; i++){
          if (i > d2) p2[i] = 0; // setting array[i] to zero when it gets outside the defined grade
          cout << (p1[i]+p2[i])<< endl;

          cout << "pi1( "<< i << "): "<< p1[i] << endl;
          cout << "pi2( "<< i << "): "<< p2[i] << endl << endl;
          dr++;
        }
    }
    cout << "dr: "<< dr << endl;

    return 0;


}

int main()
{
  double *p1;
  double *p2;
  int g1, g2, g3;

  p1=read_poly(g1);

  p2 = read_second_poly(g2);

  poli_sum(p1,g1, p2, g2, g3);

  delete[] p1;
  delete[] p2;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You check if `d1 > d2` and, if it is, you immediately do `p2[i] = 0` all the way up to `d1`. Assuming `p2` has size `d2`, it doesn't have `d1` elements, because your if statement just ensured that it's too small.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Yes, I'm filling the missing grades with 0 to calculate (p1[i]+p2[i]). However, the "read_poly"-function ensures that the number of p2[] elements is equal to the grade. Actually, there is even one more element in p2[2] as 0 is also a grade (c + cx + cx^2 ...). This has been working perfectly for (d1 <=d2)

Comment: In both branches, `p1[i] = 0` and `p2[i] = 0` is Undefined Behavior because you're writing past the end of the allocated arrays. (Undefined Behavior includes appearing to work properly.) Don't write to either of your polynomial arrays in that function.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to find a different approach then

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but the two functions `get_poly` and `get_second_poly` do exactly the same thing, except for the prompt. The code to create and populate the polynomial should be in a single function. Also, use `std::vector<double>` to manage the array. That way you don’t have to handle the sizes separately.

Comment: If your code works correctly when `d1 <= d2`, all you need to do to handle  `d1 > d2` is swap `d2` and `d1`. Basically, `if (d1 <= d2) add(d1, d2) else add(d2, d1);`.

Comment: This urgently needs `std::vector` instead of all these `new[]` allocations flying all over the place. Also `poli_sum` only ever returns `0` which means it should be of type `void`. C++ should use `nullptr`, not `0` or `NULL`.